# Search date related data from the string concatenated with dates from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB. I have this scenario where data is to be retrieved such that we only need data either for the whole week or for weekdays only, depending upon the condition.

The secondary attribute contains the data like

```
<some id>##<user_id>##<year>##<month>##<day>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I need this solution for database DynamoDB and backend Ruby Sinatra.

Comment: Is secondary attribute the same as the sort key?

Comment: sort key contains more data, but also includes the date in the above format.